# Django - Collector dependencies does not include models in which the deleteable model is a nullable field

Tags: python, django

Supposing I have the following models:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ...

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)

class Baz(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, null=True, blank=True)
```

If I tried to use the Django Collector to get the dependencies of a `Foo`, as follows, I would get all the dependencies, including `Bar`, except for `Baz`:

```
from django.db.models.deletion import Collector

def get_related_models(obj):
    collector = Collector(using='default')    
    collector.collect([obj])
    return collector.dependencies.get(obj.__class__, set())

get_related_models(Foo.objects.get(pk=1))
```

The reason, I suspect, was that `Foo` was a nullable field in `Baz`, so `Collector` probably thinks deleting a `Foo` would only make the corresponding `Baz` object's `Foo` field point to null. However, if you delete a `Foo` the related `Baz` would be deleted too.

I would like to inform my users that `Baz` is dependent on `Foo`, despite the `Foo` field in `Baz` being nullable.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution involves overriding the `Collector.add` method from `django.db.models.deletion` so that nullable relations are no longer ignored:

```
def add(...):
    # same default code goes here
    ...

    # overriden behavior (check for nullable was removed)
    if source is not None:
        # same code
        ....
```

I'm not sure if it's the best solution, but the application was working fine since I've committed the code. I'll update this answer (or remove it) if some issues caused by it will occur.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this -->

```
from django.contrib.admin.utils import NestedObjects
    
def get_related_models(obj):
    collector = NestedObjects(using="default")
    collector.collect([obj])
    return collector.dependencies.get(obj.__class__, set())
    

get_related_models(Foo.objects.get(pk=1))
```